# Pick date format from locales in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have included given code in my en-US.yml

```
en-US:
  date:
    formats:
          default: "%m-%d-%Y"
          long: "%B %d, %Y"
          short: "%b %d"
```

and I want to show format short so for this  I have given

```
@title=  I18n.l (Time.now, format: :short)
```

its not working it gives me

> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'

Please guide me how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a typo `I18n.l (...)` whitespace after `I18n.l`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this syntax for giving format type:

```
I18n.l Time.now, :format => :short
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a space after `I18n.l`.

You might want to check the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)